# Linking Check boxes to Array Items

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have a function in which i store arrays that have ratings for Films. The film ratings split into 3 categories 15, 18, PG and those values are already stored in the arrays.

I want to create a checkbox for those 3 options and then link them to the array so that it will display the name of the film or films that have the rating that was clicked.

Unfortunately i cant share any of my code for a number of reasons but simply what i am asking is how to link the value of the checkbox to the item that has the same value in the array.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Add an event listener for the checkbox

Comment: Can you show any code? you can usually change just the names of variables or whatnot pretty easily and still protect your application.

Answer (score 0):

Store the arrays in an object, whose key is the rating:

```
var films = {
    "15": [ "Film1", "Film2", ...],
    "18": [ "Film3", "Film4", ...],
    "PG": [ "Film5", "Film6", ...]
};
```

Then when the user clicks on a checkbox, you can display `films[this.value]` in the click handler function.